# Using media queries to achieve responsive body background

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm designing a responsive website with a fixed wallpaper, below is my .CSS code:

```
body {
  background: url(/path...) no-repeat fixed !important;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover
}
/* Custom, iPhone Retina- Personal comment: mobile portrait */

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  body {
    background: url(images/mobile_dark_bg0.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 40px
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 25px
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 22px
  }
  p {
    font-size: 20px
  }
  .p2, .p3 {
    font-size: 18px
  }
}
/* Extra Small Devices, Phones- Personal comment: mobile landscape */

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  body {
    background: url(images/mobile_dark_bg1.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 40px
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 25px
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 22px
  }
  p {
    font-size: 20px
  }
  .p2, .p3 {
    font-size: 18px
  }
}
/* Small Devices, Tablets */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background: url(images/bg_img.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 40px
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 25px
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 22px
  }
  p {
    font-size: 20px
  }
  .p2, .p3 {
    font-size: 18px
  }
}
/* Medium Devices, Desktops */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  body {
    background: url(images/bg_img.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%
  }
}
```

Note that I'm "changing the original body background, with another one inside the media queries, to achieve the responsive background of the page".

But the background is always messed up, either zoomed up, or there's a white gap in the bottom; it works on small and extra small, but the bigger the screen, the more messed up it gets.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question should contain [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

If your background is having a white gap at the bottom, maybe try:

```
html, body {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

`100vh` will allow the page to be the height of the device rather than `100%` of the container height.

Comment: I also recommend adding width:100vw when using "cover" just to ensure the image spans the whole width of the page regardless of the viewport being wider than your image.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `no-repeat center center fixed`

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  body {
    background: url(images/bg_img.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

This works for me. `no-repeat center center fixed` makes my image disappear completely.